# How to change default bash globbing?

Tags: bash, glob

I have a Makefile which has this line :

$(CROSS_COMPILE)$(CC) $(DLFLAGS) $(LIBPATH) -o $(OUTP)/$(SONAME) *.o $(LIBINCL)

This *.o expansion sometimes looks like 1.0 2.o 3.o 4.o. However, other times it can be 2.o 1.o 4.o 3.o (and other combinations). This causes the resulting shared object to have different checksums.

As a limited workaround, in some cases we change the line above to this :

$(CROSS_COMPILE)$(CC) $(DLFLAGS) $(LIBPATH) -o $(OUTP)/$(SONAME) $(sort $(wildcard *.o)) $(LIBINCL)

However, I can't do this fix for every source package. What I would like is for the shell (bash) to perform the glob substitution based on a sort of the filename, so that the '*.o' glob substitution above is consistent between machines and builds.

Any ideas ? Can I tell bash to (by default) change how it does globbing to accomplish what I want ?

Comment: I would expect globbing to return the same order all the time. See this discussion for example http://superuser.com/questions/192280/does-bashs-match-files-in-alphanumeric-order

Comment: Watch your language related environment setting in `$LANG`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to count on wildcard expansion to return filenames in a specific order -- but if you know that the filenames will be in a certain numeric interval, why not use brace expansion (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)?

```
$ echo {1..4}.o
1.o 2.o 3.o 4.o
```